# Prove $n^3$ has the form $9k$ or $9k + 1$ or $9k + 8$ for some integer $k$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $n$ be an integer. Prove $n^3$ has the form $9k$ or $9k + 1$ or $9k + 8$ for some integer $k$.

Comment: Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any number can be written as one of $3k-1$, $3k$ or $3k + 1$ for some $k$. It's obvious what happens in the $3k$ case. Otherwise,
$$ (3k \pm 1)^3 = 27k^3 \pm 3 \cdot 9k^2 + 3 \cdot 3k \pm 1 \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{9}. $$

Answer (score 0):

You could start this way: every integer has the form $9k+m$ for some $m=0,1,\ldots,8$. That gives you $9$ different kinds of integer. Cube each one, and see what you get. For example:

$$\begin{align}(9k+2)^3 &= 9^3k^3 + 3\cdot9^2k^2\cdot2 + 3\cdot 9k\cdot4 + 8\\
&=9(9^2k^3 + 3\cdot9k^2\cdot2 + 3k\cdot4)+8\\
&=9K+8
\end{align}$$

You can do a similar calculation for each value of $m$, and see what you come up with!